# how to access the intermittent data from an observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am asking an Observable question that has been asked in many variations normally without checked answers. I very new to Observables so bear with me.
This is my scenario:

1. I have a very large db I want to pull data from every 5 secs using an index to advance my position in the db...(don't ask why I am doing it this way). I have now problem here I use a do....while(more) with a timeout between each call and I get all my data. The problem arises in between calls I need to present the interim data to the UI but I can't because using a promise (which I am accustom to ) will not give me the interim data...so I am looking to Observable to help solve the problem....but still I am not getting the interim data. This is what I am doing:

UI

```html
<div *ngIf="!count_started"> 
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="start(id)">
        <h1>START</h1>
    </button> 
</div>
<div>
    <button *ngIf="count_started && partial_count" mat-raised-button> 
        <h1>Loading.......</h1>
    </button> 
</div> 
<div *ngIf="interim_data_ready">
    {{ interim data$ }}
</div>
    <button *ngIf="count_completed" mat-raised-button> 
        <h1>Loading....completed</h1>
    </button> 
</div>
```

COMPONENT.TS

```js
interim_data_ready = false;
let wait = (ms: number => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

    -----------------------

start(id: any){
this.count_started = true;
this.partial_count = true;
this.more_data = true;
    
do {
    let interimData$ = this.start_count.subscribe(val => val);
        
    // I need access to interimData$  array length and objects
    // if (interimData$ != null){ this.intermin_data_ready = true;
    //                            reset the value of this.skip }
    // if (interimData$ = null) { this.more_data= false}
} while(this.more_data)
           
    ------------------------
 

start_count = new Observable((count) =>{
    count.next(this.getInterimValueFromDB()) 
})

    ------------------------

getInterimValueFromDB(){
    await wait(5000);
    const interimData = getDataService.getData(this.skip,this.limit) 
    return interimData;
}
```

I am sure there's a best practice of doing this with Observables and I am most likely way off. I would appreciate any help in structuring this the correct way. You may also notice I am using this.skip and this.limit instead of passing params...that's because I couldn't figure out how using the Observable.

Answer (score 3):

You should have a look at [interval](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/interval) operator. You can use it as a trigger do "increase your index in database". Furthermore you can use the [tap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/tap) to have access to results.

In pseudocode it can look like:

```js
interval(5000).pipe(
    tap( //getDataService.getData),
    tap(results => // do with result what you want),
    tap( // increase your index in a side effect)
).subscribe();
```

Comment: interesting....I will explore and report back.

Comment: @dafoldedeing How do I terminate the interval? I understand you have to unsubscribe to it...but how do I do that within the pipe?

Comment: declare `subscription: Subscription` and then initialize your interval like this:
`this.subscription = interval(...)` and then `subscription.unsubscribe()`

Answer (score 0):

### Polling

While the previous answer should work fine, it is a good practice to try and avoid side effects in your observables. In other words to not actually 'DO' anything that changes state in `tap` operators.

Also, using interval, you would only start polling after the first 5000ms have transpired, which will feel like an eternity to the user.

You can use the `timer` function for polling, which allows to start polling right away and the `takeUntil` operator to complete the observable.

component.ts:

```js
private stopPolling = new Subject();

this.interimData$ = timer(1, 5000).pipe(
     switchMap(() => this.getDataService.getData(/*...*/)),
     retry(), // Retry when the call fails (don't wait 5s)
     // ...
     takeUntil(this.stopPolling) // Stop when stopPolling fires
);

ngOnDestroy() {
    // You can fire this observable anywhere and interimData$ will complete
    // It doesn't have to be in the OnDestroy lifecyclehook
    this.stopPolling.next();
}
```

Also, you do not have to subscribe in your component, and you can use an async pipe on the observable in your template.

component.html:

```
{{ interimData$ | async }}
```

You can use the async pipe on observables anywhere in your template, when it needs to be used/transformed in the template you might need to add braces, e.g: `(interimData$ | async)`

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want polling. It can be achieved the following way

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ngemzu?file=index.ts

```js
const dbData = [
  ['user 1', 'user 2'],
  ['user 3', 'user 4'],
  ['user 5', 'user 6'],
];

function getFromDb(index: number) {
  return dbData[index] ? of(dbData[index]) : of(null);
}

function getPollSub() {
  let index = 0;

  return defer(() => getFromDb(index)).pipe(
    tap(() => index++),
    repeat({ delay: 3000 }), // repeat subscribing to the source observable indefinitely with 3sec delay between response and making a new request
    takeWhile((val) => !!val),
    scan((acc, val) => {
      // scan is like reduce but it iterates over emitted values over time and the final subscriber has access to the intermedieate values
      if (!acc) acc = [];

      if (!val) return acc;

      return acc.concat(val); // combine old values in the array with the new anrrived data and return to the subscriber
    })
  );
}

getPollSub().subscribe(
  (val) => {
    console.log('get new val');
    document.body.innerHTML = `<pre>${JSON.stringify(val, null, 2)}</pre>`;
  },
  (err) => {
    console.error(err);
  },
  () => {
    console.log('Completed');
  }
);
```

Here we initiate the requests to a DB, using `scan` operator we digest new values and combine them with the values we had before. This way we have just one observable with no extra variables containing the result.

Then this can be simply put into the template using `async` pipe with no need of manual subscription management.

`defer` is used in order to prevent execution of the function when JS parses the code, so it can be resubscribed properly multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve a basic offset based pagination, you can use [`timer`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/timer) with [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap). `timer` will emit at the specified interval and `switchMap` will subscribe to an inner observable and emit its emissions.

Since timer will emit sequential integers beginning with 0, `skip` can be determined by taking that integer multiplied by the limit:

```js
polledItems$ = timer(0, POLL_INTERVAL).pipe(
    switchMap(n => this.service.getData(n*LIMIT, LIMIT))
);
```

You can use [`scan`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/scan) to accumulate items from multiple emissions into a single array and emit as emissions are received.  You pass a function to `scan` that receives the previously emitted value, along with the current emission.  Whatever that function returns will be emitted:

```js
allItems$ = polledItems$.pipe(
    scan((allItems, items) => allItems.concat(items), [])
);
```

Since you know to stop polling once the items comes back as `null`, we can add `takeWhile` to end the stream when the condition returns `false`:

```js
allItems$ = polledItems$.pipe(
    takeWhile(items => !!items, true),
    scan((allItems, items) => allItems.concat(items), [])
);
```

You could then use this `allItems$` observable in your template with the [`async`](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe#description) pipe like this:

```html
<ul *ngIf="allItems$ | async as items">
    <li *ngFor="let item of items">
        {{ item.name }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

---

However, instead of merely creating an observable that emits the collection of items, we could design a single observable that emits all the "state" your view needs including an `items` property that represents the collection of all fetched items.

The minimum state our view would need to do its work might look like this:

```js
interface State {
  items      : Item[];
  isMore     : boolean;
  buttonText : string;
}
```

Now, inside of our `scan`, instead of returning an array of items, we will return an entire `State` for our view.  Since `scan` will not emit until it receives an emission, we can use [`startWith`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/startwith) to emit an initial value:

```js
const INITIAL_STATE: State = {
  items      : undefined,
  isMore     : false,
  buttonText : 'START'
};

state$ = this.polledItems$.pipe(
  scan((state, incomingItems) => {
    const isMore = !!incomingItems;
    const newItems = incomingItems ?? [];
    const items = state.items ? state.items.concat(newItems) : newItems;

    return { items, isMore, buttonText: isMore ? 'Loading...' : 'DONE' };
  }, INITIAL_STATE),
  startWith({items: [], isMore: true, buttonText: 'Loading...' })
);
```

To kick off the emission from a button click, we can use a [`Subject`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects) as a trigger to start our polling.  We can also pull out the state reducer logic into its own function, to make the observable easier to read:

```js
  private start$ = new Subject<void>();

  state$: Observable<State> = this.start$.pipe(
    exhaustMap(() => this.polledItems$.pipe(
      scan(stateReducerFn, INITIAL_POLL_STATE),
      startWith(INITIAL_POLL_STATE)
    )),
    startWith(INITIAL_STATE)
  );

  start() {
    this.start$.next();
  }
```

Here's a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-72177868?devtoolsheight=60&file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) demo.